# Unintentionally Overlapping Android Views

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-xml

My xml file uses the android DrawerLayout. It shows the Toolbar and RecyclerView upon opening the app which is what I want, but when I open the drawer and click an option, the RecyclerView and fragment that was clicked are overlapping.

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/profileDrawer"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/no_robots"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/157fbps.png[/IMG]

I'm bringing the fragment to the front using this line in my main activity

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: And what do you want it to look like?

Comment: When I click an item in the nav drawer, I want that to be the only thing seen other than toolbar. So imagine it without the cards that say hp and vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the activity has multiple containers:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame2">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/no_robots"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You are loading your fragment in the FrameLayout, but you still have the RecyclerView. You should only have a FrameLayout in the activity XML, and your fragment will load the RecyclerView, TextView or whatever you want in there. As it is now, you seem to be loading your fragment in the FrameLayout, while leaving the RecyclerView in place, which causes the overlap.

Your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profileDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: so I need to remove the listview?

Comment: No, remove the contents of the FrameLayout and inflate your fragments in that FrameLayout. Alternatively, if the RecyclerView is in your activity and not in a fragment, then set the visibility to GONE when you inflate a fragment. But ideally the RecyclerView should be moved to a fragment.

Comment: I think i need to set the visibility to gone like you said since it is in my activity. Thank you!

Comment: Do mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE); where you add the fragment. Don't forget to set it back to visible when you want to show it again.

Comment: View.VISIBLE, yes.

Comment: Last question. There are 3 cases for my nav drawer. case 2 and 3 show fragments. Case 1 is supposed to show the home screen. How could I make the fragment no longer visible on case 1?

Comment: Unload the fragment, getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(<your fragment here>).commit();  -- but this wil all be simpler if whatever you do in case 1 was just another fragment, so you would not have to worry about setting visibility or unloading fragments, as the replace call on fragment maanger would unload the previous fragment for you.

Comment: perfect! I was doing that, but was forgetting .commit() on the end. Thank you for your help!